# Is there anyway I can boolean a smoothed surface without making it look deformed?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm trying to create some holes that are shaped as X's onto the smoothed surface, but it ends up making the surface look deformed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an edge split modifier to make the newly created edges sharp.

If this doesn't help, try using Blender 2.8 the boolean operation got improved.

Comment: the edge split modifier worked. thank you so much.